# Adding elements to Vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

I am converting a function in MatLab to C++ and come across this (in matlab):

```
  f = blocks(min:max,1:len);
```

with values: **min = 153, max = 205**

It is a 2D vector. So does the line of code above create a new 2D vector and copy the all of the blocks inside "blocks" to the new vector?

So in essence, it's essentially a loop that starts at 153 ending at 250 and copies each of the blocks to the new vector?

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That statement takes rows between `min` and `max` and columns between `1` and `len` from `blocks` matrix and assigns them to `f`.

Let's give this a try:

```
M = magic(5) % gives

M =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

M2 = M(2:4,1:3) % rows 2 to 4, columns 1 to 3

M2 =

    23     5     7
     4     6    13
    10    12    19
```

I don't know C++ well but probably you will need 2 `for` loops to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If `blocks` is a 2d matrix, that code extracts a submatrix of it and assigns it to the variable `f`. The extracted submatrix is row `min` to row `max` and column `1` to column `len`.

For more info, you should read [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=94401003a394cb167adbe8819636).

If you want to do this in a loop (not that efficient in matlab, but I don't know how you're going to work it out in C++), it is identical to the following:

```
f = NaN(max-min+1,len); % allocate memory for f
for rowi=1:(max-(min-1))
    f(rowi,:) =  blocks(rowi + min-1, 1:len);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That line of code copies the element of the submatrix between the elements [153,1] and [205,len] of `blocks` to the newly created matrix `f`.
Ported in C that would be:

```
int f[max-min+1][len]; // or float or whatever
for(int ii=0; ii<=max-min; ii++)
    for(int jj=0; jj<len; jj++)
        f[ii][jj] = blocks[ii+min][jj];
```

I'm assuming now min and max contains the index starting to count from 0 (ie: 152 and 204), not 1, like you would do in matlab.

**update:**
otherwise, more performant (since is only a single for loop which copies the while line)

```
for(ii=0; ii<=max-min; ii++)
    memcpy( &f2[ii][0], &blocks[min+ii][0], sizeof(int)*(len) );
```